# Why can't I use cd in a bash script?

Tags: bash, debian

I made a very simple script

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir $1 && cd $1
```

when I execute

```
myscript test
```

It creates test directory but doesn't go inside just after. I don't understand why, on my fedora 27 this script works without any issue but on my debian stretch this behavior occurs. Could someone explain why I am having this bug.

Answer (score 4):

You can and it works perfectly.  But when the script is done, its environment (including *its* working directory) is destroyed.

Try `source myscript test` to execute your script as though you had typed its commands into your actual interactive shell and you working directory will have been changed.